# Gallery script is not working on dynamically appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a purchased Isotope gallery plugin, that scans all elements in certain gallery container and add/remove classes as needed, depending on the gallery filtering.

The problem is that I'm now getting the elements dynamically, so the gallery script is working ok for the default loaded elements, but once I click 'load more' to get more elements from DB, the elements are inserted ok to the container but I need to execute that gallery init function again, after append.

I have tried adding this script to the html head tag:

```
  <script>
    function reload_js(src) {
       jQuery('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
        jQuery('<script>').attr('src', src).appendTo('head');
    }
    </script>
```

and then I'm calling `reload_js` right after `$("#container").append(data);` 
but still the appended elements don't have the extra classes they should have.

any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a like for the gallery manual?

Comment: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: What gallery plugin are you using?

Comment: Ussually there is an initializing function that gets called when the page is loaded. You need to call this function after you append new elements. Your reload_js doesn't do the trick, probably because the code is wrapped in document.load function

Comment: You have the [append](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#appended) method

Comment: Try calling $grid.isotope('layout'); after appending a new element with "append".

Comment: thanks that help me search in a different direction and go deeper into this specific plugin doc , found helpful info here too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896464/how-to-get-isotope-working-with-dynamic-dom-nodes

Comment: the line i needed was : $("#containerisotope").isotope('insert',$(data));

Comment: That's less code than in my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer is to be found on the [documentation page](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#adding-and-removing-items).

When appending an element the following way

```
// create new item elements
var $items = $('<div class="grid-item">...</div>');
// append items to grid
$grid.append( $items )
// add and lay out newly appended items
.isotope( 'appended', $items )
// sort grid
.isotope({ sortBy : 'symbol' });
```

your gallery should be laid out newly.

Comment: now its working, i'm able to add new elements, but the filtering is not good. the new elements are not sorted correctly

Comment: Check http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html#sortby. I'll add a line of code to my example.

Comment: Did you set 'sortBy' and 'getSortData' when initialising the plugin? See example on http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html#insert

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved it ! thanks for all helpers :)

so the line to insert elements to isotop gallery :
the line i needed was : $("#containerisotope").isotope('insert',$(data));

important - this does all the work for you, no need to use jquery append. just this line insert and filter correctly all new elements.

link to isotop doc: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/adding-items.html